# preg_replace php syntax code

Tags: php, syntax, preg-replace

I need replace `","` with `|,|` inside pattern without replace any other place

i have like this code

```
[word:"pla pla","pla pla","[other_word:"pla pla","[word:"pla","pla"end word]","pla pla"end other_word]","pla pla","[word:"pla","pla"end word]"end word]
```

result must be like this

```
[word:"pla pla|,|pla pla|,|[other_word:"pla pla","[word:"pla","pla"end word]","pla pla"end other_word]|,|pla pla|,|[word:"pla","pla"end word]"end word]
```

my curent code is :

```
preg_replace('/\[([\w]+):\"[^\",\"]*\"end\s\w\](.*?)\[([\w]+):\"\"end\s\w\]/', '|^|', $syn);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern is designed to replace `","` only inside the first level or square brackets:

```
$pattern = '~
# this part defines subpatterns to be used later in the main pattern
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<nestedBrackets> \[ [^][]* (?:\g<nestedBrackets>[^][]*)*+ ] )
)

# the main pattern
(?:            # two possible entry points
    \G(?!\A)   # 1. contiguous to a previous match
  |            #   OR
    [^[]* \[   # 2. all characters until an opening bracket
)

# all possible characters until "," or the closing bracket:
[^]["]* # all that is not ] [ or "
(?:
    \g<nestedBrackets> [^]["]* # possible nested brackets
  |                            #   OR
    "(?!,") [^]["]*            # a quote not followed by ,"
)*+  # repeat as needed
\K   # remove all on the left from match result
(?:
    ","           # match the target
  |
    ] (*SKIP)(*F) # closing bracket: break the contiguity
)
~x';

$str = preg_replace($pattern, '|,|', $str);
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/nM2dN1/1)